# Do you know a wysiwyg in YUI 3?

Tags: javascript, yui, wysiwyg

is there an implentation of Yahoo Text Editor but with YUI3 ? I'm looking for a way to create very easily a wysiwyg using YUI3.

Any idea ?

( sorry for my english .. )

Comment: I don't agree with the closing of the question, YUI(3) users (like me) know very well what the question is that's being asked. I would agree if they had said "too simple", possibly :-) but with the reason given I remain in opposition to the motion of the court.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an editor widget as a FRAMEWORK - meaning it comes without buttons etc., it is just a plain iframe that is created, and the basic editor functionality exists, but there are no GUI elements for a user to do anything.

See http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/editor/

It is very easy to supply buttons, basically, this is a widget for programmers and not for out-of-the-box use.

I don't want to chide you (too much) for asking this question, but this is apparent from the YUI3 project pages quite clearly.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I wondered if there is a kind of plugin with a GUI

Comment: See the yui3 gallery - there is only a pretty old one, so since there have been quite a few chances since to the Y.Editor widget I believe that gallery widget won't even work any more (with the latest YUI3.5.0). Not a big deal, just use any of the hand full of widely used full-featured editor widgets. Myself, I used the YUI3 Y.Editor one, but I only needed basic editing (<10 buttons total for various styles), so for me it was ideal, the other ones having WAY too much stuff.